# How to disable alert "restore internet security settings" in "windows 10"

Tags: windows-10, gpedit

I have a Windows 10 Home edition, and I don't have gpedit.msc because this version doesn't have group policy. I read that you need that to disable the bothering reminding that my security settings are not good (just because I don't want to be asked a question every time that I decide to execute an *.exe file).

is there a way to circumnavigate this problem without have to install a Group Policy on the system? (I read that might get messy)

Thank you

Comment: You can consult the registry key at https://www.windows-security.org/c57498930096f5d5a5551f6ae32d39ca/prevent-fix-settings-functionality as well as follow the other steps at http://superuser.com/questions/972424/how-can-i-stop-windows-10-from-nagging-me-to-restore-internet-security-settings?rq=1

Comment: There is no "Internet Explorer" folder in my HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE. I am looking for it but I am still not finding it. And as I said... Group Policy doesn't exist on my windows version.

Comment: Absent folders need to be created; given the policy is not yet configured, the folder is absent

Comment: So you mean that I need to create that folder? and than create a file to disable the security setting? what are the steps?

Comment: I've found an explanation with two possible solutions which includes steps at http://swimminginthought.com/disabling-internet-explorer-security-settings-check-solved/

Comment: It give me an error when I created the *.reg file with the information inside. "Cannot import ... is not a registry script. You can only import binary registry files from within the registry..." etc... In the other method I do not know how create a folder file in the registry (I don't see any option that let me do so.)

Comment: Ok found a solution on how to fix that. http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/create-reg-file-for-registry-hacks As well one of the solution on the links where missing the "/" chars for defining folder.

Comment: To chime in, one of Super User's very best contributors has a great tutorial regarding how to install the `gpedit.msc` capability in Windows 10 Home:  [Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit, how do I install it?](http://superuser.com/q/1018145/650163)

Comment: @Run5k The problem is that you are not obtaining the Group Policy Editor from Microsoft, as well as that it could possibly be altered.

Comment: @TomWijsman , while those are certainly valid points this entire process has been very thoroughly vetted by DavidPostill and Moab.  Needless to say, if you aren't comfortable with the limiting factors you don't need to utilize it, but it seems to be a viable option.

Comment: Thorough automated analysis reveals no malicious behavior, of that we can be certain without manual vetting; this does not make this legal or compatible, just a word of warning